# Need help creating Java Linear Algorithm n(k-1)

Tags: java, arrays, object

I'm finding common elements in a collection of arrays. This is my code so far.

```
public class CommonElements {       

Object[] comparable;
Object[] comparisonArray;
Object[] commonArray;
int comparisonCount  = 0;


// constructor 
public CommonElements( String comparableString, int i ){ 

    comparable[i] = comparableString;  
}



public void addCommonElements( String comparableString, int i ){

    comparable[i] = comparableString;  
}



public Object[] getCommonElements(){

    return comparable;
}




public void SetcomparisonCount(int i){

    comparisonCount = i;
}



public int getcomparisonCount(){

    return comparisonCount;
}



public Comparable[] findCommonElements(Object[] collections){

    comparable = ((Comparable[])collections[0]);


    for(int i = 0; i <comparable.length; i++ ){


        for(int j = 0; j < collections.length; j++){


        }

    }




    return null;
}   



}





public class Module6 {


public static void main(String[] agrs){

Object [] collections = new Object[3];
collections[0] = new String[]{"Pittsburgh", "New York", "Chicago", "Cleveland", "Miami", "Dallas", "Atlanta", "Detroit"};
collections[1] = new String[]{"Philadelphia", "Seattle", "Tampa Bay", "Cincinnati", "New Orleans", "Houston", "Jacksonville","Minnesota"};
collections[2] = new String[] {"Indianapolis", "Oakland", "Baltimore", "Buffalo", "San Francisco", "Washington", "Green Bay", "St. Louis"};


}



}


public Comparable[] findCommonElements(Object[] collection)
```

I'm using this method to help sort through my array. The method accepts a collection of arrays (of varying length and of any type) as input, the algorithm input should be no greater than n(k-1). I know I can solve it using a quadratic algorithm, but it won't meet the requirement of the assignment. Can some one give me any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Here is note my teacher provided.

Note About Testing
You will need to develop several sets of test collections for testing your algorithm. The grading rubric mentions covering the case where all the test collections have the same length, as well as covering the case where the test collections are of different lengths. You will also need to think about what constitutes the worst case scenario for this algorithm, since only that scenario will make your analysis of total comparisons performed a meaningful one. You can use the formulas in the grading rubric to tell you how many comparisons you should expect in the quadratic and linear cases. For example, if you have 5 total collections (1 query collection and 4 test collections), each of which contains 10 elements, the total number of comparisons performed in the worst case should be: (k - 1)N2, which for k = 10 and N = 10 is: (5 - 1)102, or 400 comparisons. For the linear algorithm, you should only have N*(k - 1), which is 10*(5 - 1), or 40 comparisons.

Comment: Please work on improving the clarity of your question. What is the actual problem your code is attempting to solve? What is `n`? What is `k`?

Comment: Well there really is not a problem yet. I'm taking a data structure and algorithm for my CS class. My professor gave us an assignment to write an efficient algorithm. The problem is to get the full 30 pts on the assignment I need create a linear algorithm.

Comment: I added additional information in my question.

Answer (score 0):

hmm, sound like you need first k elements.  If I am right:
Read about **quick sort** and idea of **partition element**, it allows you to pick k-th greatest element in linear time,
so to pick k first elements you will spend n*(k-1).
I can't give more details, because it is you homework, so interesting part is left for you.

Comment: Okay sure will. I really just wanted an idea on how I solve this. Thanks!

Comment: I'll be sure to come back if I have any more questions.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor throws NullPointerException

```
public CommonElements( String comparableString, int i ){ 

 //NullPointerException   
comparable[i] = comparableString; 


}
```

You have to create object first

```
Object[] comparable = new Object[10];;
```